# Filter Query to List Resources based on Tags Field Conditions. Filter Query for Many-to-Many SQL Relation Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

Writing query to filter list of Resources based on multiple tags field conditions as per example: `WHERE tag_name != fabric or tag_name = user`.

Basically, I have list of resources which assigned with multiple tags{name:value}. Need a way to query filter list of resources based on tags fields {name & value} with various operations like equal & not equal values.

Three Tables:

1. Resource Table: Res_ID, Res_Name
2. Tag Table: Tag_ID, Tag_Name, Tag_Value
3. Ref_Res_Tag: Res_ID, Tag_ID

Queries which I've came up with:

Query 1:

```
SELECT "sample_t"."name", "tag_t"."tag_name" from "sample" as sample_t
LEFT JOIN "ref_sample_tag" as ref_sample_tag_t on "ref_sample_tag_t"."from" = "sample_t"."uuid"
LEFT JOIN "tag" as tag_t on "tag_t"."uuid" = "ref_sample_tag_t"."to"
WHERE ("tag_t"."tag_name" != 'fabric');
```

Problem with Q1: This query is returning Sample1, Sample2 for above query.
Expectation: {Empty} : Result should be empty as all resources are tagged to fabric.

Query 2:

```
SELECT "sample_t"."name" FROM "sample" as sample_t
WHERE sample_t.uuid NOT IN
         (SELECT ref_sample_tag.FROM from ref_sample_tag
          LEFT JOIN tag AS tag_t ON ref_sample_tag.to = tag_t.uuid WHERE tag_t.tag_name = 'fabric')
```

Result: {} : No Resource as all tagged to fabric. Expected Result.

Problem: How to use multiple different tag field conditions, like `((tag_name != 'fabric') or (tag_name = 'user'))`

Please let me know for more details required.

Comment: Postgresql and mysql are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use.

Comment: I am using both SQL variants. MySQL & Postgres. Any of these two variant solution will work for me.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) so it can be copied to be used when testing an answer. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. That was typo, I have update with user.
In query 2: WHERE tag_name != fabric or tag_name = abc, this won't work. 
Expected result : {} - Empty list as all resources are tagged to fabric.

Answer (score 1):

Based on extra data provided I think this should work

```
SELECT * FROM "sample" as sample_result 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(

SELECT 1
    from "sample" as sample_t 
    INNER JOIN "ref_sample_tag" as ref_sample_tag_t 
          on "ref_sample_tag_t"."from" = "sample_t"."uuid" 
    INNER JOIN "tag" as tag_t 
           on "tag_t"."uuid" = "ref_sample_tag_t"."to" 
    WHERE ("tag_t"."tag_name" = 'name')
    AND  "sample_t"."uuid" ="sample_result"."uuid"
) 
AND EXISTS
(

SELECT 1
    from "sample" as sample_t 
    INNER JOIN "ref_sample_tag" as ref_sample_tag_t 
          on "ref_sample_tag_t"."from" = "sample_t"."uuid" 
    INNER JOIN "tag" as tag_t 
           on "tag_t"."uuid" = "ref_sample_tag_t"."to" 
    WHERE ("tag_t"."tag_name" = 'fabric')
    AND  "sample_t"."uuid" ="sample_result"."uuid"
)
```

;

Comment: @NikunjGupta see updated answer. This has two EXISTS checks which check for absence and presence of tag

Comment: Thanks @DhruvJoshi, for your answer. Yes it is working but performance wise it seems like it will take too much time on high number of records.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Postgres it's easier to aggregate the tags into an array, then apply the condition on the array:

So query 1 would be:

```
select *
from (
  select r.res_id, r.res_name,  
         array_agg(distinct t.tag_name) as tags
  from resource r
    join ref_res_tag rrt on rrt.res_id = r.res_id
    join tag t on t.tag_id = rrt.tag_id
  group by r.res_id, r.res_name
) t  
where 'fabric' <> all(tags)
```

For query 2, you can just add:

```
   or 'user' = any(tags);
```

If you need to query for the tag name **and** tag value, you can aggregate the tags into JSON arrays, then use the JSON operators, e.g. to find all resources that have "fabric: one":

```
select *
from (
  select r.res_id, r.res_name,  
         jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(t.tag_name, t.tag_value)) as tags
  from resource r
    join ref_res_tag rrt on rrt.res_id = r.res_id
    join tag t on t.tag_id = rrt.tag_id
  group by r.res_id, r.res_name
) t  
where tags @> '[{"fabric": "one"}]';
```

That would also return resource that have e.g. fabric two as well.

To get those that **only** have fabric one, you need to filter during aggregation and use an equality in the final WHERE clause:

```
select *
from (
  select r.res_id, r.res_name,  
         jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(t.tag_name, t.tag_value)) as tags
  from resource r
    join ref_res_tag rrt on rrt.res_id = r.res_id
    join tag t on t.tag_id = rrt.tag_id
  where t.tag_name = 'fabric'
  group by r.res_id, r.res_name
) t  
where tags = '[{"fabric": "one"}]';
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't understand your above line saying that - For query 2'or 'user = any(tags);'' ?

In your last query, if where clause is 'fabric:one' , fabric two should not come.

Comment: For the second query, just add the condition `or 'user' = any(tags)` to the WHERE clause.

Comment: @NikunjGupta "*fabric two should not come*" - does this mean a resource can be assigned the same tag with different values?

Comment: T1: {name: fabric, value:one} and T2: {name: fabric, value: two} : these two are different tags. Yes any tag can be assigned to resource. let say T1 & T2 both can assigned to Resource. This is same as tagging to any resource where tag has {key:value} pair

Comment: Really Appreciated for your efforts. 
Single query should work for multiple different combinations of tags.

1. Conditon: where (tag_name = "fabric" and tag_value = "one")
    Expected Result: {Sample1}

2. Condition: where (tag_name = "fabric")
    Expected Result: {Sample1, Sample2, Sample3}

3. Condition: where (tag_name != "fabric")
    Expected Result: {}

4. Condition: where ((tag_name = fabric) or (tag_name != user))
    Expected Result: {Sample3}